# Using avconv to select only one audio channel in output

Tags: avconv

I have a two-channel AAC file and I am trying to get two separate AAC files, each of which with one of the two channels in the original AAC file. Is there an option in avconv that does that? 
Something like:

```
avconv -channel=0 -i input.aac input_ch1.aac

avconv -channel=1 -i input.aac input_ch2.aac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

This works for an input stereo aac file that has front left and front right channels.

`avconv -i input.aac -filter_complex channelsplit="channel_layout=2[FL][FR]" -map [FL] channel1.aac -map [FR] channel2.aac`

In case your input file has more than two channels, you can map each channel (either by name as in FL, or by their index starting from zero) to a separate single-channel file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to *channels* (as opposed to streams), the following `ffmpeg` command should work:

```
ffmpeg -i input.aac -map_channel 0.0.0 left.aac -map_channel 0.0.1 right.aac
```

Comment: I need avconv command, ffmpeg doesn't work on the new version of Ubuntu for aac files.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You tagged your question with `ffmpeg`, implying that this would be an acceptable solution. Have you tried the `channelmap` filter?

Comment: Yeah I thought people with ffmpeg experience know the solution in avconv. No I didn't try that. To be honest, I didn't know how to use that.

Comment: Just in case `channelmap` worked out, can you please post your solution so that others finding this thread can benefit? I don't use avconv myself, so I wouldn't know. You can post your own answer, it edit mine.

Comment: Sure, I just answered my own question :)